# How much I can use from React in Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

noticed that most ReactNative projects uses :

```
const Thing = () => {...
```

or

```
export default function Thing() {...
```

instead of using actual components like :

```
class Thing extends Component {
```

is extending Component more for ReactJS ? Cause I need this for lifecycle hooks like

```
componentDidMount() {...
```

is it possible to have those hooks in native (translated in ObjectiveC and Java) or is it purely JS ? My question is : how much I can keep from ReactJS in ReactNative ?

Thanks a lot, S.

Answer (score 0):

React native works in a similar way to normal react.

- There is the class based component approach and there is the function based approach in both cases.

You can use the class based approach if you need to but since [React 16](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) sometime in 2018 the function based approach with hooks may be the better way to go. Both systems work so you can try whichever way is comfortable with you.

So to answer your question you can keep most of it but you would have to use items from react native like `<View>` instead of `<div>` and `<TextInput>` instead of `<input>`

To handle componentDidMount/componentDidUpdate you can using hooks you can use `useEffect` or `useLayoutEffect` in the functional case which `in my opinion` are better approaches but may take a while to get used to

Comment: Merciii !......

Comment: Merci ! 
So absolutely everything is translated into ObjectiveC (iOS) or Java (Android) : hooks, properties, states, dom, Contexte, etc. ?
Using Expo to test my app in phone simulator, I tried a JS function alert("hello"); and it worked ! I was very surprised... it is not supposed to. Is Expo purely web/js and simulates every native iOS / Android UI ?

Comment: Yes, that is the native part of react native, expo is a good start to get comfortable but may be limitting in some cases

Comment: this may be of assistance if you are just starting https://reactnative.dev/docs/tutorial